# Check if users are friends before sending push notification in parse.com cloud code

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm almost ready to release an iOS app on the app store, but I'm having trouble switching from client to cloud code push notifications.

Each user in the app has a "user" object in parse, and they each have a property (array) of friends.

I want users to be able to send each other notifications, but I don't want client push to be enabled for security purposes.

Essentially, when a user sends a message to a friend, I want cloud code to check if the user is on their friend's friends list, and if they are, send the push notification with the message to that friend.